# Getting metadata from a radio stream using MPMoviePlayer? (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mpmovieplayercontroller, avaudioplayer

I am using **MPMoviePlayer** for radio streaming and i need to get the current track info.

Can anyone help me as to how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to set a `NSNotification` so that you can get the data at specific intervals, like so:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                      selector:@selector(StreamMeta:)
                                      name:MPMoviePlayerTimedMetadataUpdatedNotification
                                      object:nil];
```

Next, you create the method. I am going to use **streamMPMoviePlayer** as the name of your `MPMoviePlayerController` and **metaString** as the `NSString` which will store the metadata values:

```
- (void)StreamMeta:(NSNotification*)notification
{
  if ([streamMPMoviePlayer timedMetadata] != nil) {
      MPTimedMetadata *meta = [[streamMPMoviePlayer timedMetadata] objectAtIndex:0];
      metaString = meta.value; // gives the NSString the artist/song information
  }
  else {
     // No metadata available
  }
}
```

Comment: See this is for MPMusicPlayer. I am asking for MPMoviePlayer Online streaming i.e radio url streaming.

Comment: @user2174560 Glad to hear! Feel free to upvote my answer if it did :)

Comment: @DSG can you tell me how this can be done when I am using `AVPlayer`?